# pipeline script to execute jobs on different nodes (slave) configured in Jenins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins server (version 2.34.2) installed in a VM linux ubuntu 16.04. I would like executing different jobs on two different slaves with a pipeline script. I already add my slave by configuring nodes in Jenkins.

I try with this code:

```
node('MASTER'){

    stage 'Initialisation Socket MASTER'
     echo "INITIALISATION SOCKET MASTER....."
     sh 'javac /home/user/TCPEchoServer.java'
     sh 'cd /home/user java TCPEchoServer'

}

node('slave'){

    stage 'Initialisation Socket SLAVE'
     echo "INITIALISATION SOCKET SLAVE....."
     sh 'javac /home/user/TCPEchoClient.java'
     sh 'cd /home/user java TCPEchoClient 160.98.34.85 2007'

}
```

Here is the configuration of my node "slave"
[Node - Slave - configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz2hA.png)

But I can't executing some job on this node. Someone can help me please ?

THANKS

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I restart my Jenkins.. and I don't know why it's working yet :) thx